# Javascript concat and overwrite where element has the same id

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to concat two arrays with objects and let the second array overwrite the first array where they have the same id:

```
// array 1
[
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},
    {id: 3, name: "baz"}
]

// array 2:
[
    {id: 1, name: "newFoo"},
    {id: 4, name: "y"},
    {id: 5, name: "z"}
]

// out:
[
    {id: 1, name: "newFoo"}, // overwriten by array 2
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},   // not changed (from array 1)
    {id: 3, name: "baz"},  // not changed (from array 1)
    {id: 4, name: "y"},   // added (from array 2)
    {id: 5, name: "z"}   // added (from array 2)
]
```

If it is possible I would like to do this without the use of third party libraries

Comment: Yes there are many approches to do this. Either push and extend element from the 2nd into 1st, if their id's match. Else iterate array as an object with id as the key and extend, then convert it back to an array.

Comment: Alright, I am trying something out, can you maybe give an example as answer ???

Comment: posted it as an answer ...

Comment: Damn guys, so many answers and I can only rate one as "correct", thanx to all off you and this is the proof that the community of developers is the best <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = [
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},
    {id: 3, name: "baz"}
];

var b = [
    {id: 1, name: "fooboo"},
    {id: 4, name: "bar"},
    {id: 5, name: "baz"}
];

/* iterate through each of b, if match found in a, extend with that of a. else push into b ...*/
b.forEach(m => {
 var item = a.find(n => n.id === m.id);
 if(item) { return Object.assign(item, m); }
 a.push(m);
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
let arr1 = [
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},
    {id: 3, name: "baz"}
]

let arr2 = [
    {id: 1, name: "newFoo"},
    {id: 4, name: "y"},
    {id: 5, name: "z"}
]
let result = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b.id] = b.name;
    return a;
},{})
result = Object.keys(result).map(e => {
  return {id : e, name : result[e]};
});
console.log(result);
```

> Explanation

I am using the property of objects that they don't keep duplicate keys, so for an array concated  together, I reduce it to an object with id as it's key and name as its value, hence overriding all duplicates. In the next step I converted this back into an array.

Comment: Nicely done. In addition to the code, you should provide an explanation.

Comment: Nice work @marvel308. Think we really dont need the first 2 `Object.assign` because to the 1st reduce, you are passing a new object as the initial value and for the 2nd reduce you can pass the same object as the initial value.

Comment: yeah using concat to avoid redundancy of the function

Answer (score 0):

Check you my solution. There is no "rewrite", i just use a second array as base and don't write value if it has same id.

```js
let a = [
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},
    {id: 3, name: "baz"}
];

let b = [
    {id: 1, name: "newFoo"},
    {id: 4, name: "y"},
    {id: 5, name: "z"}
];

let duplicateId;

a.forEach(aitem => {
 duplicateId = false;
 b.forEach(bitem => {
   if (aitem.id === bitem.id)
     duplicateId = true;
  });
  if (!duplicateId)
    b.push(aitem);
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Object.assign and Object.entries to achieve, lets say:

```
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, name: "foo"},
    {id: 2, name: "bar"},
    {id: 3, name: "baz"}
]

const arr2 = [
    {id: 1, name: "newFoo"},
    {id: 4, name: "y"},
    {id: 5, name: "z"}
 ]

const obj3 = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...arr1, arr2))
       .map(([prop, value]) => ({[prop]:value}));
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0f75vLka/

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to convert arrays to map with id as key then merge the objects and then convert it back to array.

```
var arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: "foo"},
  {id: 2, name: "bar"},
  {id: 3, name: "baz"}
];

var arr2 = [
  {id: 1, name: "newFoo"},
  {id: 4, name: "y"},
  {id: 5, name: "z"}
];

function arr2map(arr) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    map[item.id] = item;
  }
  return map;
}

function map2arr(map) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i in map) {
    arr.push(map[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

var arr1m = arr2map(arr1);
var arr2m = arr2map(arr2);
var arr3m = map2arr( Object.assign({}, arr1m, arr2m) );

//output
alert(JSON.stringify(arr3m));
```